# Private beta sites show up on user pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I can see private beta sites on my userpage, but not on the account tab. It seems like the correct behavior would be to hide the private beta site.

[image]

Comment: @Nick What exactly does "completed" mean here? That it's now shown on the accounts tab as well, or that it's hidden on the userpage?

Comment: @CodesInChaos hidden in both, like br.stackoverflow currently is - since linking you to a 404 isn't nice

Answer (score 3):

Your participation in the private beta is public knowledge: it's even advertised.

That is, all Area 51 proposal pages list the committers for a proposal (who are automatically made private beta members) and a beta site's most active users, even for private beta.

You can see the list for Movies right here:

> [Movies - Area 51 - Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies)

Beyond that, the private beta's data and activity exposed to the API, and we can see everything that's going on anyway by using sites like [Stack Mobile](http://stackmobile.com/movies.stackexchange.com).

But I guess a more direct answer to this is, there's no point in hiding this information: if all goes well, your site, and all activity you've done so far on the site while it's in private beta, will be public anyway in a few days.

Comment: This makes sense, but why does the account tab hide it?

Comment: @Pubby That seems like a bug/oversight, given it's advertised almost everywhere else.